# Sybase ASE monitoring tool of choice

Tags: sybase, nagios, ganglia, cacti, sybase-ase15

I have inherited an Sybase ASE 16 database server and my initial task consist on deploy some Key Performance Indicators to monitor the RDBMS instance performance.

I have 3 tools available in the company:

- Cacti
- Nagios
- Ganglia

And I'd like to have easy to read, nice-looking performance graphs like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS71M.png

I'm starting to look for information about configurations to be made to achieve this.

Any advice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross posted on dba.stackexchange, and is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Guao. Only 5 views and the only answer I've got is one who ask to close the question? Never mind, I'll ask someone to eliminate it inmediatly, since no one's willing to collaborate.

Comment: check spotlight might help you

Comment: We are using asemon